# comparing records using scan in abinitio

Tags: ab-initio

I have 3  records  in a file need to compare them fields by fields if there is no change oldest records must go to o/p else if there is change  eg if  record 2 has changed wrt to record 1 need to send both records to o/p . how to do this using scan component in abinitio

I have tried using reformat need to do using scan